# Create nested Pie chart from two dictionaries using Matplotlib and Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have two dictionaries: one contains the labour cost for a process and the other contains the materials cost. I would like to create a nested pie chart to show the ratio of labour to material cost of each process. Im not sure how to get the data out of the dictionaries and into a list of tuples so I can then use `np.array` and put into `Matplotlib`.

These are the dictionaries..

```py
labour_cost_dict = {'Solder': 240, 'weld': 3, 'glue': 400}
mat_cost_dict = {'Solder': 100, 'weld': 13, 'glue': 20}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is? Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic]. As an aside, is a nested pie chart really the best format for the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you only have single value for each key, you can extract a list this way.

```py
dict_to_array = lambda x:np.array([value for _,value in x.items()])
In [11]: labor_arr = dict_to_array(labour_cost_dict)
Out[11]: [240, 3, 400]
In [29]: final_arr = np.vstack((labour_arr, mat_arr))

In [30]: final_arr
Out[30]: 
array([[240,   3, 400],
       [100,  13,  20]])
```

And then you can convert them to np array and plot the pie chart. Since its not exactly clear how you want your pie chart to be, you can plot using the example [provided](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/nested_pie.html)